# GetAsyncKeyState() causes anti-virus program to flag as keylogger

Tags: winapi, keyboard, message-queue

I have been building a very small game in the Windows API, and in the main message loop I use GetAsyncKeyState() to test if a user is pressing the arrow buttons. I use this instead of WM_KEYDOWN because with WM_KEYDOWN there is an initial pause after the first press, and I don't want to modify a user's settings. My antivirus program flags the game as a keylogger program, is there an alternative way about this?

Comment: Well I can see it's point, but this is how you track keys in XNA for instance, does it complain about those? Maybe it's just a little to aggresive?

Comment: I have yet to program in XNA, so I didn't even know that function was used there. My anti-virus program is Kaspersky, which is very aggressive in protection, but I would trust my entire computer in their hands. I'll just have to make an exception for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the anti-virus program supposed to guess that you are *not* using GetAsyncKeyState() to spy on the keyboard and log keys?  You tell it of course, make an exclusion.  If you're worried that your future customers are not so easily convinced then go back to using WM_KEYDOWN/UP.  Use an array of 256 bools to keep track of the key state.  Set it to true on DOWN, regardless of how many you get, false on UP.  Also check if the scanner is happy when you stop calling the API function when your app loses focus.  Pay attention to WM_ACTIVATEAPP.