# Does "getAsyncKeyState" trigger Anti-Virus programs c++

Tags: c++, hotkeys, antivirus

I'm trying to code a plugin for OBS for Windows and I need to handle key-press events, now I've seen (1)[two posts](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/105443/) (2)[where people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409885/getasynckeystate-causes-anti-virus-program-to-flag-as-keylogger) mention that their anti-virus catches

```
#include <windows.h>

//...

if( GetAsyncKeyState( VK_UP ) & 0x8000 )
{
    // the 'Up' arrow key is currently being held down
}

if( GetAsyncKeyState( 'A' ) & 0x8000 )
{
    // the 'A' key is currently being held down
}
```

as a keylogger, there's one anti-virus named specificaly - `Kaspersky`

Is this true, and are there any more anti-virus programs that trigger on GetAsyncKeyState, because the anti-virus program thinks that it's a keylogger, if so are there any better methods to handle key-press events in c++?

Comment: Have you tested these claims?  It's a free download and a few lines of code.  Most games/game engines use this API.

Comment: @RichardCritten Not yet, I was about to create a test dll for it

Answer (score 0):

An over-zealous antivirus can detect anything as malicious.

GetAsyncKeyState() detection is likely part of the antivirus's hieuristic engine, but it is unlikely that this single rule would trigger protection by an antivirus.  There are probably additional properties of your binary which in combination with GetASyncKeyState() detection would trigger a warning.

It would be odd for an anti-virus to trigger only for this one reason, as it's a Windows API function that is very common.

Keep in mind anti-virus frequently update and it is normal for false positives to be solved as problems with these signatures are detected.

Checkout this plugin's source code to learn how to handle input with OBS plugins [input-overlay](https://github.com/univrsal/input-overlay)